# C programming: logarithmic index array

Tags: c, indexing, series

I'm trying to decimate a given vector with a logarithmic rule instead of a linear one.

e.g.:

The given vector has 100 elements. I want to reduce it to a vector of 10 elements that are the same elements of the starting vector taken with a logarithmic rule on the *int* interval [0,99].

I hope to be clear enough. Any help is appreciated !

Have a nice day !

Comment: No.. It's not clear enough.! + add some code to show what you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudo-code :

```
int n; // Length of subsampled array

for i:
   new_array[i] = array[(int)(log(i)/log(n)*length(array))]
```

Is that what you are trying to do ?